# Fast Search in cloud version of SharPoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is Fast Search available in [Office 365](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/Pages/Try.aspx) (a cloud version of SharePoint 2013)?

Answer (score -1):

yes. Every version of SharePoint 2013, including foundation and 365 has FAST Search

Comment: Do you have any reference(Microsoft Link) for this information?